# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint . Cannot insert duplicate key in object - ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to insert the data of a new person and I can at the first attempt but when and on the second attempt gives error violation of primary key and in fact, the person id (personId) is incremented each time it is trying to add a new person and so I realized the error is the primary key

table person

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] (
    [personID]    INT NOT NULL,
    [personName] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([personID] ASC)
);
```

method to create and insert the new person

```
protected void BtnCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      //id to new person
      int id = 0;
      //command
      string command = "INSERT INTO [Person] ([personID], [personName]) VALUES (@id, @name)";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id++);//id increase
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
      connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Go to your database schema and change the personID column adding the IDENTITY property. Then remove any attempt to set yourself the value for personID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not concerned with the actual value of your `personID` field, (which your code seems to indicate).  And, just want it to be unique and increment by 1.

In illustration of what @Steve has indicated, you could define your table that way:  (in T-SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] (
[personID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[personName] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([personID] ASC)
);
```

This will then eliminate your need to insert the personID

```
protected void BtnCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

      //command
      string command = "INSERT INTO [Person] ([personName]) VALUES (@name)";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
      connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current code cannot work a second time because the `id` variable that you  increment is a local variable allocated on the stack. When the method exits, everything on the stack is cleared. Clicking again the button you reenter the method but the variable is reset to zero and your increment sets again the variable to 1. Thus the duplicate exception for the personID field.

I recommend to change your `personID` column adding the [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) property.
In this way the database calculates itself the next value to assign to the `personID` field and you don't need to remember what was the last id assigned to the table (and this is practically impossible to achieve in a safe way in a multiuser environment)

After adding the IDENTITY property, you could read back the value assigned by the database to your `personID` field changing your query to

```
string command = @"INSERT INTO [Person] ([personName]) 
                   OUTPUT INSERTED.personID
                   VALUES (@name)";
```

and running the query using ExecuteScalar

```
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, all your answers are correct but I found a better solution for my case, I used the id as a static value initialized at least one and put out of function and it worked with no errors and works as I wanted and I thank your time and availability

my table don´t need to use identity because I intend to enter the ID increment every time you clicked on the button to create new person

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] (
    [personID]    INT NOT NULL,
    [personName] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([personID] ASC)
);
```

I used `static int id = -1`, out of function and it´s work fine

```
//id to new person
private static int id = -1;

protected void BtnCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

      //command
      string command = "INSERT INTO [Person] ([personID], [personName]) VALUES (@id, @name)";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id++);//id increase
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
      connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve has a good answer, alternatively if can't re-arrange you DB schema, then you can do this:

```
protected void BtnCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

  connection.Open();

  SqlCommand idcommand = new SqlCommand("select max([personID]) from Person", connection)
  //id to new person
  int id = ((int)idcommand.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
  //command
  string command = "INSERT INTO [Person] ([personID], [personName]) VALUES (@id, @name)";

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id++);//id increase
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this. The problem with MAX is when you have more than one user that inserts records. Sooner or later you get an error because MAX could return the same value to more than one user. Another (minor) problem is the fact that in this way you go two times to the database and this could impact the performance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either, this is posted as an *alternative* - There are some legacy cases where you can't can't change the DB schema.